# Is it possible to write a SQL for all matchs in a triple join with no unions?

Tags: sql, database, join, query-optimization

I'd like to perform a SQL join for the grey painted region of the following Venn diagram, but using no UNIONs:

[image: Venn diagram triple join]

Please, is it possible?

For the sake of simplicity, think all tables with only two columns: *id* and *value*, *id* is the same for all of them.

Here's a sample data:

```
Set A
| id | value   |
----------------
| 1  | red     |
| 2  | magenta |
| 3  | white   |
| 4  | yellow  |

Set B
| id | value   |
----------------
| 2  | magenta |
| 3  | white   |
| 5  | blue    |
| 6  | cyan    |

Set C
| id | value   |
----------------
| 7  | green   |
| 3  | white   |
| 4  | yellow  |
| 6  | cyan    |

Resulting set
| id | value   |
----------------
| 2  | magenta |
| 3  | white   |
| 4  | yellow  |
| 6  | cyan    |
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: No one in special, because the code have to be portable. So, you can assume a SQL-92 target.

Comment: What do you want returned exactly? All id, value combos? And what is the reason for not wanting to use `union`? Is this a "puzzler" or something?

Comment: The real one will have to return several columns, so I simplified things here and just *id* and *value* are necessary. The reason for avoid unions is because the tables are huge.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help much more than an abstract diagram.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, as you requested.

Comment: @YorgaBabuscan . . . Then GMB's answer should answer your question, although you need to include `id` in the `select` and perhaps in the `using` clauses as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, his aswer is very good, but I'm just giving some time to olhers to try another or enrich that. Meanwhile, I've trying to figure out why this question got a downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `full join` twice and add conditional logic in the `where` clause:

```
select id
from a
full join b using(id)
full join c using(id)
where 
    case when a.id is not null then 1 else 0 end
        + case when b.id is not null then 1 else 0 end
        + case when c.id is not null then 1 else 0 end
    > 1
```

Not all databases support that syntax. A more widely supported approach is indeed to use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id
from (
    select id from a
    union all select id from b
    union all select id from c
) t
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: . . The OP has elaborated on the problem, which means that you should adjust your answer to include the second column.  Then the OP can accept it.